# Django DRF 3.9.2 breaks my ViewSet actions

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I've updated DRF to 3.9.2 and now my actions break with the very weird:

```
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Upon closer inspection, it seems the handler method is simply defined as `'Name'` and so trying to call a string results in a `TypeError`:

```
# Get the appropriate handler method
if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
    # request.method.lower() is 'post' so self.post returns 'Name'
    handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(),
                      self.http_method_not_allowed)
else:
    handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
```

This is my viewset:

```py
class ValidateViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    @action(methods=('post',), detail=False, permission_classes=())
    def name(self, request):
        response, code = self.validate(request.data, NameSerializer)
        return Response(response, code)
```

and this is how I register it:

```py
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(
    'customer/register/validate',
    contact_registration.ValidateViewSet,
    'customer-register-validate',
)
```

This works perfectly fine in 3.8.2 but I'm not sure exactly what changed in 3.9.0 onwards that it's no longer good.

EDIT: Looks like renaming the action from `name` to something else fixes it, is `name` reserved somehow?

EDIT: After going through the 3.9.0 PRs, I suspect [this](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/5605/files#diff-faaea574b0b229b4c6ccf6078f194d17) is the culprit as it introduces a class variable called `name`. I think that should be at least documented if not fixed.

EDIT: [Issue raised](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6490), seems like the best option is to document these more explicitly.